# jQuery Validation Plugin - Minimum amount for text input based on radio button checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

The HTML:

```
<form method="post" class="form" action="/forms/" id="basicDonationForm" name="basicDonationForm">
   <div class="line">
      <div class="control">
         <label>Method of Payment:</label>
         <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="basicDonationFormPayMethod" id="basicDonationFormPayMethodCC" value="Credit Card">
            <input type="radio" name="basicDonationFormPayMethod" id="basicDonationFormPayMethodOther" vaue="Other">
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="line" style="padding-bottom:20px;">
   <div class="control">
      <label for="basicDonationFormAmount">Amount you will donate:</label>
      <input type="text" name="basicDonationFormAmount" id="basicDonationFormAmount">
      </div
   </div>
   <div class="line line-buttons"><a class="button" href="javascript:void(0);"><span>Submit</span></a></div>
</form>
```

The amount field needs to be:

- minimum of 18 if basicDonationFormPayMethodCC is checked
- minimum of 10 if basicDonationFormPayMethodOther is checked

The rules I thus far have:

```
rules: {
    basicDonationFormPayMethod: {
        required: true
    },
    basicDonationFormAmount: {
        number: true,
        required: true,
        special: true
    }
}
```

I've begun to use `jQuery.validator.addMethod()`, but all of the examples I find use a passed parameter to check against the element's value. I am unsure of the syntax needed to compare one form element against another using one element's rule.

My javascript:

```
    jQuery.validator.addMethod("special", function (value, element, param) {
        if ($("input[name='basicDonationFormPayMethod']:checked").length > 0){
            var currentDonation = $("#basicDonationFormAmount").val();
            var radioVal = $('input:radio[name=basicDonationFormPayMethod]:checked').val();
            if (radioVal == 'Credit Card') {
                if (currentDonation >= 18) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            } else {
                if (currentDonation >= 10) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            return false;
        };
    }, "Choose payment method and enter $18 or more for credit, $10 or more for other");
```

It works, but it feels too bloated. I would like to simplify my custom method, if syntax inherit to the plugin allows for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to write a custom method to simply implement a conditional rule.  It can be done with a function within the `rules` object.

Something like this...

```
rules: {
    basicDonationFormPayMethod: {
        required: true
    },
    basicDonationFormAmount: {
        number: true,
        required: true,
        min: function() {
            return ($('input:radio[name=basicDonationFormPayMethod]:checked').val() == "Credit Card") ? 18 : 10;
        }
    }
},
messages: {
    basicDonationFormAmount: {
        min: "Choose payment method and enter $18 or more for credit, $10 or more for other"
    }
}
```